# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

It is a well discussed problem, but I can't find the  issue (I've been researching it for days now); `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

jQuery seems not te be loaded within my custom template. So I pass the jQuery 
 argument when enqueuing the script:

```
// Load scripts in header
function html5blank_header_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/assets/scripts_head.js', array('jquery'), '1.2', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
}
```

I use jQuery in non-conflicting mode and it is wrapped in `document ready function`:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    // case carousel
    jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {
        jQuery('.slider_sector').slick({
            infinite: true,
            speed: 600,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            accessibility: true,
            centerMode: true,
            lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
            variableWidth: true
        });
    });
});
```

When including jQuery manually by inserting `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in the head, the error goes away.

I should not have to load jQuery manually if `array('jquery')` is passed while loading right?

Comment: "jQuery seems not to be loaded". Have you looked for it in page source and verified this? Have you tried this with a different template in your theme? Have you tested with a default theme to see if the theme is responsible? Have you disabled plugins to see if it is a plugin conflict?

Comment: Which hook are you running `html5blank_header_scripts` on? Are you using the jQuery that's bundled with WP? Or is it being deregistered and re-added to use a CDN?